# Fastest Truck in ETS 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

Now that the 90kmph Speed limit is gone after the 1.4.12 patch, does anybody know which is the fastest truck in the game and what speeds it can achieve?

Comment: I have mangaed to reach speeds of 140kph in my Scania. I wanna know if others have achieved better speeds with the same or other trucks.

Comment: update! reached 156 kmph with my Scania R630 on a flat road.Need more updates on other trucks.

Comment: Depends on what you consider fastest. If by "fastest" you understand acceleration, then the quickest truck should be the Volvo with 750HP and the 6-speed gearbox. The second quickest would be the Scania, again, with the 6-speed gearbox. The 6-speed just shifts gears a lot faster than the rest. If you want the fastest as in top speed, it gets a bit more complicated. Top speed is governed by several factors: horsepower, RPM limit, last gear ratio and differential ratio. We will assume that the tyre diameter is the same for all trucks.

Comment: People assume the fastest is the Volvo (see the current highest ranked answer) until I start gapping them with what is in fact the fastest truck, simply because they overlook the above factors, specifically, the RPM limit which, on the Volvo, is limited to 2000. 

Let's assume that all trucks have the same tyre with a diameter equal to 1.04 meters. That would mean the circumference is 1.04m * PI = 3.27m. So, the wheel, spinning at 1 RPM, would travel with a speed of 3.27 meters per minute, or 0.1962 Km/H.

Comment: The best gear box (for top speed) is the gearbox with the smallest final drive ratio. For the Volvo, that would be the I-Shift ATO3512D(R), with a last gear ratio of 0.78, diff ratio of 3.08 and, therefore, a final drive ratio of 3.08*0.78 ~2.4. This means that the Volvo's top speed is 2000 RPM / 2.4 * 0.1962 = 163.5 KM/h. Taking the Volvo with this gearbox for a drive you would see that it would not travel faster than 163 KMH.

Comment: The fastest trucks in the game are either of the two Scanias with the 730 HP engines and the Opticruise GRSO 905(R) gearbox. This has a last gear ratio of 0.8, diff ratio of 3.08 and, therefore, a final drive ratio of 3.08*0.8 ~2.46. 
At this point you would say that this ratio is bigger, and you would be correct, but the Scania makes up for this by having an engine that will rev to 2500 RPM.

This means that the Scania's top speed is 2500 RPM / 2.46 * 0.1962 = 199.4 KM/h.

Comment: Those extra 500 RPM really add up. This is, however, only the theoretical top speed. Taking the Scania out for a drive and you will be able to drive at a constant 170 Km/H speed on a level, straight piece of road. Still, this is 7 Km/H faster than the Volvo. Also, I was able to reach 185 Km/H with the Scania going downhill. Were there to be a downhill road long enough, I assume I would be able to reach 199 Km/H, whereas the Volvo won't go past 163 because of that darn 2K RPM limit.

Comment: If the load is too heavy and the Scania can't go past 2000 RPM, then both trucks would be just as fast. The extra 30 HP the Volvo has just won't make that much of a difference. How fast you are able to climb up in the gears and how much speed you will be able to carry through the corners and while weaving through traffic will have a much greater impact on what truck is faster than those measly 30 HP.

BUT, as long as the load is light enough to allow the Scania to go over 2000 RPM in the last gear, the Scania is the fastest truck in the game by a healthy margin.

Comment: And yes, this isn't a comment, it's an answer, but because of the oligophrenic rules of this website, I can't post these comments as an answer since I don't have the reputation to do it, even though I think my reputation on the other stack exchange websites is good enough.

Answer (score 8):

The fastest is the truck from Volvo, the globetrotter XL.
It gets unlocked at Level 16, it has 750 horsepower and produces a torque of 3500nM. It goes up to 165 with load.

Comment: Just did over 150km/h with that baby on a level road.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest truck in Euro Truck Simulator is the **Scania R730**.

With 730Hp, it is the most powerful engine in Euro Truck Simulator 2.

---

It is the **most expensive one from Scania** (and the game), **costing 212.430 Euros**.

You can buy it in **Milano** (Italy), **Hannover** (Germany) or **Manchester** (England).

*(Maybe you can buy it in another stand, I didn't search them all)*

Comment: Could you let me know what speeds have you achieved with this truck without any trailers?

Comment: I didn't since I drove a MAN in my save.
In a little search, I found this video on YouTube where the author reaches 301 km/h (187 mph):
http://youtu.be/8vTN_vo7pEc

Comment: That is clearly modded, and it says so in the description. That thing has 10,000bhp. If this is the basis for your answer then sorry, it is not right.

Comment: Scania R with DC16 21 730 euro 5 v8 engine:
730hp, 16 liters

Answer (score 3):

All trucks can get to 130+ km/h regardless of the engine, granted some cannot get to that speed on straights. I'm still driving my starter Volvo with a 700hp engine at level 10 and have no problem reaching that speed even in straights.